# Is there a way to reassign form data that is submitted to the wrong case in CommCare?

Tags: commcare

If I submit form data on a mobile device against the wrong case in CommCare, is there a way to reassign that form data to the correct case? Or is the only course correction to archive that form and resubmit that data against the correct case?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately once a form has been submitted against a case there is no way to change the case it modifies. The way to correct the action is to archive the form and resubmit the data against the new case.